# pattern matching a filename in R

Tags: regex, r, esri

This is probably real simple, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I have an application in R (Shiny) where a user uploads to the application a *.zip file that contains all the components of an ESRI shapefile.  I unpack these files into their own directory.  This folder then, may or may not, contain a *.shp.xml file.  At some point in my R code, I need to find the exact name of the *.shp file that has been unpacked, and distinguish it from the *.shp.xml file.  How do I write the expression that will do that?  I was thinking to use list.files, but I am unsure how to write the rest of the expression.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With R regex patterns the "$" has special meaning as the end of a character element  (and the 'dots' need to be escaped with `\\`, so

```
shpfils <- list.files(path, pattern="\\.shp$")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should isolate your file -
`Sys.glob("*shp")`
as compared to 
`Sys.glob("*shp*")`
which should give both the files
or 
`Sys.glob("*shp.xml")`
which should give the .shp.xml file